# Programmatically open zip file menu C#

Tags: c#, zip, c#-ziparchive

I am trying to save files zipped into one file in a wpf application.
[image: Zip Archive]

After Save I want to open the archive as shown in the image above programmatically. I am using Dot Net framework 4.0. I have tried using ZipFile, ZipPackage classes to implement the above. But could not find a way.Please help with your thoughts.

Comment: try this https://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think there is nothing to do with "zip". It's operating system feature.
Try this;

```
        var zipFilePath = @"C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\A Minor Pentatonic.zip";
        Process.Start("explorer.exe", zipFilePath);
```

Result;
[image]

Comment: Cannot use Process.Start . Fortify flags it as command injection  :(

Comment: Well, that's another topic. And is this fortify a security application? Or code analyzer( http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/static-code-analysis-sast/ )? If it's code analyzer, try to ignore it. Because AVG, Avast, Comodo and Eset antimalware systems allows "Process.Start" command if anti-malware software is not working on realtime-high-heuristic analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your views. I got a solution which stands fortify scan and opens the file. I used ShellExecute and DllImport user32. That solved my issue.